# Invalid Write Valgrind

Tags: c, malloc, undefined, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a function which insert a `Person` into an array of pointer to `Person`, where `Person` is defined as:

```
typedef struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
} Person;
```

And my insert method is:

```
static void insert(Person **arr, char *name, int age) {
    static int next_free_place = 0;
    /* put name and age into the next free place in the array parameter here */
    Person *next_person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if (!next_person) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory");
        exit(-1);
    }
    next_person->name = name;
    next_person->age = age;
    *(arr + next_free_place) = next_person;  // INVALID WRITE HERE FROM VALGRIND

    // move on to next location
    next_free_place++;
}
```

My main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    /* declare the people array here */
    Person **people = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) {
        insert(people, names[i], ages[i]);
    }

    /* print the people array here*/
    for (int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s, Age: %d\n", people[i]->name, people[i]->age);
    }

    free(people);
    return 0;
}
```

In the header file:

```
#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
                      "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};
```

When I run my program I get `Segmentation Fault` and Valgrind shows there is an invalid write as indicated above.
May I know why this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: @MayurK I just added my main in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Write -- Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635084/invalid-write-valgrind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you did not allocate memory for the array of pointers to objects of the type Person. So the program has undefined behavior when you are trying to derefernce the pointer people (or arr within the function):

```
*(arr + next_free_place) = next_person;
```

Secondly you also need to free all allocated memory for each object in the array.

Take into account that it is a bad idea to place definitions of variables in headers. This can result in a linker error when the header is included in several translation units. You should place in a header only declarations of variables without their definitions using the specifier `extern`. The definitions should be placed in a module.

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HOW_MANY 7

char *names[HOW_MANY] = 
{
    "Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim", "Harriet"
};

unsigned int ages[HOW_MANY]= { 22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24 };

typedef struct Person 
{
    const char *name;
    unsigned int age;
} Person;

enum RETURN_CODES { Success, Full, NotEnoughMemory };

static int insert( Person **arr, const char *name, unsigned int age ) 
{
    static size_t next_free_place = 0;

    if ( next_free_place == HOW_MANY ) return Full;

    /* put name and age into the next free place in the array parameter here */
    arr[next_free_place] = malloc( sizeof( Person ) );

    if ( arr[next_free_place] == NULL ) return NotEnoughMemory;

    arr[next_free_place]->name = name;
    arr[next_free_place]->age  = age;

    ++next_free_place;

    return Success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    Person **people = calloc( HOW_MANY, sizeof( Person * ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++ ) 
    {
        insert( people, names[i], ages[i] );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "Name: %s, Age: %u\n", people[i]->name, people[i]->age );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++ ) free( people[i] );

    free( people );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Name: Simon, Age: 22
Name: Suzie, Age: 24
Name: Alfred, Age: 106
Name: Chip, Age: 6
Name: John, Age: 18
Name: Tim, Age: 32
Name: Harriet, Age: 24
```

Comment: Thanks! The explanation is very clear and helped me understand many of my other mistakes and bad practices

Comment: Sorry I accepted the other answer because it solved my problem... But your answer is definitely clearer

Comment: @Kallzvx It does not solve because as I pointed out you need also to free memory for each object in the array.:)

Comment: I have some problems to fully understand your code:`Person **people = calloc( HOW_MANY, sizeof( Person * ) );` Doesnt it allocate enough memory for all Person object?

Comment: @Kallzvx It is the same as you wrote Person *next_person = malloc(sizeof(Person)); and *(arr + next_free_place) = next_person;  only without the intermediate variable next_person.

Comment: Sorry I didnt make it clear, let me rephrase: in your code `Person **people = calloc( HOW_MANY, sizeof( Person * ) );` does it allocate memory for `Person` struct? Or just the pointer to struct? Because I see that you do another allocation in the method: `arr[next_free_place] = malloc( sizeof( Person ) );`

Comment: @Kallzvx It allocates an array of pointers to objects of the type Person. Within the function each element of the array in turn is set to the pointer to the allocated memory for a Person.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is people is not pointing anywhere. You have to create an array statically, or allocate dynamic memory for it.

Initially, `Person **people = NULL;`. When you call `insert()`, `**arr` will be pointing to NULL.

Now when you do `*(arr + next_free_place) = next_person;` you are trying to dereference a NULL pointer, which is causing the problem.

**Solution:**

```
// Static memory - Array of "HOW_MANY" pointers. In this case memory will be 
// allocated on stack. It automatically gets freed once the variable goes 
// out of scope. No explicit free() is required.
Person *people[HOW_MANY] = {NULL}; //Entire memory is set to 0/NULL automatically

// OR

// Dynamic memory - Allocate memory for "HOW_MANY" pointers.In this case 
// memory will be allocated on heap. Explicit free(people); is required.
Person **people = malloc(sizeof(Person*)*HOW_MANY);
if(NULL == people ) {/* handle this case */}
memset(people, 0x00, sizeof(Person*)*HOW_MANY); //You need to reset memory explicitly
```

Comment: Is there a difference between this two methods? I mean do they cause different behavior when using?

Comment: @Kallzvx I have updated the answer. If you are not familiar with stack and heap memories, please read about it.