# C: valgrind shows invalid write for double pointer enum in struct

Tags: c, struct, enums, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my `test.c`, I have:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

enum MyEnum{
    H1 = '#',
    H2 = '$'
};

typedef struct {
    enum MyEnum** myenum;
    int myint;
    char *s;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct* somefunction(const char* fp){
    FILE* file = fopen(fp, "r");
        if(!file){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s not found", fp);
        exit(-1);
    }
    char line[100] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    fgets(line, 100, file);
    sscanf(line, "%i", &i);
    MyStruct* strct = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(strct));
    strct->myint = i;
    printf("%i\n", strct->myint);

    fclose(file);
    free(strct);
    return strct;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  char* fp = argv[1];
  somefunction(fp);
  bool run = true;
  while(run){
    char entry = fgetc(stdin);
    
    switch(entry){ 
      case 'q' :{
        run = false;
        break;                      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `test.txt` contains:

```
1234
5678
```

Running `Valgrind` with give:

```
1234
q
==2030==
==2030== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2030== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2030==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2030==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 6,704 bytes allocated
==2030==
==2030== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2030==
==2030== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==2030==
==2030== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==2030== Invalid read of size 4
==2030==    at 0x108AA9: somefunction (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
==2030==    by 0x108B03: main (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
==2030==  Address 0x51de2f8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==2030==    at 0x4C2D0AF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==2030==    by 0x108A93: somefunction (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
==2030==    by 0x108B03: main (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
==2030==
==2030==
==2030== 1 errors in context 2 of 2:
==2030== Invalid write of size 4
==2030==    at 0x108AA2: somefunction (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
==2030==    by 0x108B03: main (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
==2030==  Address 0x51de2f8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==2030==    at 0x4C2D0AF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==2030==    by 0x108A93: somefunction (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
==2030==    by 0x108B03: main (in /root/SokobanTechDev/test)
```

Why is `valgrind` giving me an `invalid write` after defining enum `MyEnum`? In my struct, if I comment `enum MyEnum** myenum;`, those contexts disappears. I theorize that he is allocating 2 pointers (of 8 bytes each) to `H1` and `H2`, but isn't the `malloc` supposed to take care of that ?

I tried to look for some answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635084/invalid-write-valgrind?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113904/invalid-write-valgrind) but I can't seem anything related to double pointers.

Thank you in advance

Comment: why you need `    enum MyEnum** myenum;`- a double pointer ?

Comment: `MyStruct* strct = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(strct));` **-->>** `MyStruct *strct = malloc(sizeof *strct);`

Comment: @long.kl even if I don't use a double-pointer, I still would have those context errors. But this is required from me as a task.
@wildplasser, this did work. Is it because casting the `malloc` forces the double pointers to be lost?

Comment: You never need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

Comment: As a sidenote: Even if you remove he first pointer from your struct, the code still contains the same error regarding wrong size. You just don't access memory outside of the allocated memory any more until you will use member `s`.

Comment: `free(strct); return strct;` Seriously?

Comment: @Lundin it's alright to make mistakes, everybody does. I have started coding in `C` just 3 days ago...

Comment: Sure but my point is that you should be able to spot that one with a bit of manual review before even launching Valgrind. Related, it is good practice to set freed pointers to NULL if you plan to re-use them later.

Comment: @Lundin thank you for pointing it out. As you have guessed, this was used only for testing purpose... the free should come in main at the end of my program :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two bugs within the function.

The first one is an incorrect memory allocation

```
MyStruct* strct = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(strct));
```

You need to write either

```
MyStruct* strct = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(*strct));
```

or

```
MyStruct* strct = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
```

And returning the pointer with an invalid value after call free

```
    //...
    free(strct);
    return strct;
}
```

does not make a sense.